# Change a cell's value in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DataGridView in a c# windows forms application. A column of this returns (long) value.

Now I want to change it's value but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Hi Zahra, your question is tooooo brief. Add some code, picture, error (if there is any) ... something that describes your problem.

Comment: And indicate which GUI. There are multiple DataGrids in C#/.NET

Answer (score 0):

If you do binding ([C# Tutorial - Binding a DataGridView to a Collection](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection)) - it does changing automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = value;
```